# correct typing of a function with parameters in multiple forms?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, typescript-generics

I have created a utility function based on rxjs's `createSelector`.

```
  getStoreView(operators: any): Observable<any> {
    const selector = createSelector(operators);
    const storeView = this.store.select(selector);
    return storeView;
  }
```

I would like to correctly type it, such that errors in calling can be catched at compile time.

I came up with these helper types:

```
type Selectors = Record<string, Selector<State<AppState>, unknown>>;

type Observables<Type extends Selectors> = Observable<{
  [Property in keyof Type as Property]: ReturnType<Type[Property]>
}>;
```

And typed my function like this:

```
  getStoreViewNew<T extends Selectors>(operators: T): Observables<T> {
    const selector = createSelector(operators);
    const storeView = this.store.select(selector);
    return storeView;
  }
```

Now there is no type problem with the createSelector call, but the this.store.select and the return both have error messages.

Did I told to the compiler correctly that 'I have a function with a parameter which is a record of functions with different return types I do not know in advance, and my function will return an Observable of a record with the same structure, with the type of each field being the return type of the corresponding field of the parameter'?

If so, what is the problem still, and how can I get rid of it?

The error at the select call (I believe that is the relevant one):

```
const selector: MemoizedSelector<T extends Record<string, Selector<infer S, unknown>> ? S : never, { [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends Selector<T extends Record<string, Selector<infer S, unknown>> ? S : never, infer R> ? R : never; }, never>
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 9, '(mapFn: (state: AppState) => { [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends Selector<T extends Record<string, Selector<infer S, unknown>> ? S : never, infer R> ? R : never; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'MemoizedSelector<T extends Record<string, Selector<infer S, unknown>> ? S : never, { [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends Selector<T extends Record<string, Selector<infer S, unknown>> ? S : never, infer R> ? R : never; }, never>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: AppState) => { [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends Selector<T extends Record<string, Selector<infer S, unknown>> ? S : never, infer R> ? R : never; }'.
      Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
        Type 'AppState' is not assignable to type 'T extends Record<string, Selector<infer S, unknown>> ? S : never'.
  Overload 2 of 9, '(key: keyof AppState): Observable<Heroes | States>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'MemoizedSelector<T extends Record<string, Selector<infer S, unknown>> ? S : never, { [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends Selector<T extends Record<string, Selector<infer S, unknown>> ? S : never, infer R> ? R : never; }, never>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof AppState'.ts(2769)
```

playground link:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgSQHYCsCmBjGBDAIwBtM4BfOAMyghDgCIABPVAcwFci8oB6baTPQDcAKFCRYiONiiY8MTAGVMJXNAA0cZapgatu2eSo06TNlAAePAM4HBo8dHhIA8gWuYoAN0Ikj1WgZLdGt6MXAnKQBhWkhUTFR4CgC6AHJmNk5uPgFUkRFMCwl4YETPSjxsUkV8BWtEETgmqggIAC44WyhS1nVG5oJuDtR2EAJPETJ8wuK4UoUoCqq4AEEwMBr5UgR+2y3rDs260SmRGABPMGqVHAN6gF44ACUcaAATAB4uns1tW+gPmsNrVMJoWOcAHwQ0RnS6kNweby+TDWD4AFThELgjwRnh8xEwHx2-QA2gBpTDnOaoOAAa0pEEocAxVwAuh0WZhyZTWXBCgpUG96n81FBAesjqDqZRPM8sQB+Z5wYaYLwTSbQ-IXK5wXFIgnWABMH0lnM0aKx936evxJA+-SaO2azW5VNKdIZTLR7IdzTRrt5-ISQt9TRFBntzudNQEJpBnIhfSjzVKMqgz1DcAhmcVT2VcHiaqgomdUyampEjDQWFwyIAFABKApFSLYLjWYXnVDYAAWNFQwAAXrLiU1+KguuxRXWwN0fAo4LI8G8IKgiFTbAJDnZxcCthCG1JTk1WJgYDHZAA1YCYADuADk7+i+RYBUKtDdRdYIXWIFcoPI0AHMyDYdDayKohaDTOuOtidJ+BjYtIS4KOG0C-v+gFQNYDYls0sHwJuV43reSEwD2wDWAAdERmA0QhdYeDo0C4b6sgwOwUA0rR153nhx5wKe552Lxt4YZ4WHAeCoG6u4eLIh84JYk6+GrnBTH-OmjwyHIqEIehf4SXcrEwWphEiSRZEUdRtH0TojH6VAJnNOxnHcRZfH9KcpyVjEETxIkdYqRpoodKkPaeBAwAKCAqRJnAMVgFwChhR8bzAF4EIfDw6WZXkZBNjMrbtvUAASkXRZgIB+XECTwA0vp4PKYFyfqdoIIMg4dN8bBkBWY5mVAU4GHWvqzhlWyLnIK5rhuXa9v2Q5KHiwBVIc819quS1QPFTTjfOpBLjN66dHY26xkCkrZk0h4qU05GUVReBIdYG2LcOyjeKtdFCRemCiY+YmZo6wNRp1HSMWdqwSiCh73Fitl7HUVGUK0oNls0TZNN5+QiEAA

Comment: Could you provide a playground link, so we can look at the problem directly instead of guessing

Comment: Added playgroud link.